# Loop through SET variable and perform task

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to figure out how to loop through a list of SET variables and perform a simple script. This is run in batch mode. Any tips on how to adapt the following code so that it loops through the SET dir variable list?

```
SET YYYY=%date:~10,4%
ECHO Its %YYYY%

SET dir=dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4,...dirN
ECHO %dir%

:: Loop through each SET dir and perform the following.

:: Create a current year dir in remote directory
C:
cd "C:\my\dir\here\%dir%"
if not exist %YYYY% mkdir %YYYY%

:: Copy files from local to remote for each sub directory
E:
cd "E:\FTP\localdrive\%dir%"
XCOPY "E:\FTP\localdrive\%dir%" "C:\my\dir\here\%dir%\%YYYY%" /S /Y
```

After valuable comments from users, this appears to work but fails to make dirs 2 through 4.

```
 SET YYYY=%date:~10,4%
    ECHO Its %YYYY%

    SET dir=dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4

    FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (%dir%) do (
       if not exist %dir md E:\my\dir\here\%dir%
     )
```

Revised to below and still fails - "%%a was unexpected at this time" on what I think was the md E:\my\dir\here\%%a

```
SET YYYY=%date:~10,4%
ECHO Its %YYYY%

SET dir=dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (%dir%) do (
   md E:\my\dir\here\%%a
 )
```

Comment: You are looking for the [`for` command](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Comment: Lose the `/F "tokens=1 delims=,"` and just do a simple, plain FOR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for information, an alternative to the **FOR** loop method:

```
@Echo Off
(Set _yyyy=%DATE:~10,4%)
Echo= It's %_yyyy%

(Set _fold=dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4)
Echo= %_fold%

:: Loop through each Set _fold.
Call :Loop %_fold%

Pause
Exit/B

:Loop
:: Copy files from local to remote for each sub directory
If Not Exist "C:\my\dir\here\%1\%_yyyy%\" MD "C:\my\dir\here\%1\%_yyyy%"
RoboCopy "E:\FTP\localdrive\%1" "C:\my\dir\here\%1\%_yyyy%" /S
Shift
If '%1 Equ ' GoTo :EOF
GoTo :Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SET dir=dir1, dir2, dir3, dir4,...dirN

 for %%a in (%dir%) do (
    echo doing my stuff for %%a
 )
```

Comment: Post that as an edit to your question otherwise code formatting won't work

Comment: Inside the do (...) you want to change `%dir%` to `%%a`